# SQL Query Based On Month

Tags: mysql, variables, if-statement

I'm needing, if possible, to change a MySQL variable's value depending on what month it is.

Assuming that we replace -3 with a @Variable...

```
Field1 <> 1 AND (Field2 > 36000 OR Field3 < YEAR(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -3 YEAR)))
```

I need to change the [-3] to a [-2] IF the month is August or later. So January - July get [-3] while August - December get [-2].

If there is a way to do this with SQL only, that would work best for the structure of this application. If not, please let me know.

Thanks guys and gals.

Comment: There's not enough query here. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I'd be happy to do that, but I really don't understand how it could be helpful. My only question is if we can assign a value to a variable based on the current month... I think my question is a syntactical one.

Comment: i not know why you want to change the -3, but you can change it to **if(MONTH(NOW()) >7 ,-3,-2) , if(MONTH(d) >7 ,-3,-2)** or full query **ield1 <> 1 AND (Field2 > 36000 OR Field3 < YEAR(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL  if(MONTH(NOW()) >7 ,-3,-2) , if(MONTH(d) >7 ,-3,-2)  YEAR)))**

Comment: My sir, you are awesome! This is *exactly* what I was looking for. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just replace the -3 in your original expression with:
IF(MONTH(@dateVar) <= 6,-3,-2)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a `@Variable` meeting your spec like this:

```
SELECT @Variable := CASE WHEN MONTH(NOW()) >= 8 THEN 2 ELSE 3 END;
```

This will also do the trick.

```
SELECT @Variable := IF(MONTH(NOW()) >= 8, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Field1 <> 1 AND (Field2 < 36000 AND Field3 > IF(MONTH(NOW()) > 7,YEAR(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 YEAR)),YEAR(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -3 YEAR))))
```

Thank you to Mr. Buffen for inspiring the above query. It is working beautifully for me. I don't know how to make you the solution provider.